# Powershell - Cannot get -lt to work with numbers in a text file

Tags: powershell, text-files

I have a text file that is being generated hourly to determine and record free disk space. I have a process on a separate system to read that text file and determine if it is less than required for a scheduled file transfer to occur.

Problem is that the -lt statement returns true when it isn't. I believe it's due to the text file getting a CRLF added to the end, but I can't be sure.

I've tried parsing the file, splitting the data. Nothing seems to get that -lt 25 to work as expected.

**On Source System**

```
$disk = ([wmi]"\\localhost\root\cimv2:Win32_logicalDisk.DeviceID='z:'")
"{0:#.0}" -f ($disk.FreeSpace/1GB),($disk.Size/1GB) | Out-File Z:\FreeSpace\FreeSpace.txt
```

**On Remote System**

```
$Freespace = Get-Content \\Server\Freespace\FreeSpace.txt
If ($Freespace -lt 25)
  {<Send Notification> exit}
Move-Item <Localfile> <Remote Server>
```

{$Freespace -lt 25} 
always returns true. The current value is 184.6 so it shouldn't be so.

I'm at a loss here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Get-Content` returns one or more `[string]` objects, so `$Freespace` is now a string.

When you try to compare two objects of different types in PowerShell, the operator overload chosen is based on type of the left-hand side argument, and the right-hand side argument is then converted to the same type (if necessary).

Effectively, your if statement now looks like this to powershell:

```
if("184.6" -lt "25"){ ... }
```

Strings are compared *lexicographically* (or *alphabetically* if you will), and a string starting with the character `1` always comes before one that start with `2`.

Convert the `$Freespace` variable value to a numeric type with `+`:

```
if(+$Freespace -lt 25){ ... }
```